# How do I slice drop shadows in photoshop when there is another layer underneath?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have a layout of a webpage and I would like to know how to save for web all the user selected slices. However, in some particular slices I would like to only slice from one or two layers, but keep the background transparent.

Is this even possible?

If not I would have to hide all my under layers in order to save those png... not really practical at all..

Thanks for your help[image]

Comment: Unless I completely fell off the sled... This could answer your question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/photoshop-how-to-save-just-one-layer/4366#comment6203_4366

Comment: check the image I've put to show my problem

Comment: you can hide the black layer cant you?

Comment: but now image you have 1000 layers one over another. You want to update all changes. It would take long hours to export one image at once, hide layers, show layers and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart objects could help you a lot.

http://www.elated.com/articles/photoshop-smart-objects/

So, from your example images:

You would put blue and red in the same Smart object and then go to edit that smart object and slice it there as well as save in there.

1. Select layers related to the object that you need to save without a background fill ( While pressing Ctrl **or** Shift )
2. Right click one of the selected layers and choose **Convert to Smart object**
3. Then go into the Smart object's "edit mode" by right clicking the Smart object and selecting  **Edit contents** ( This brings you to basically separate document space with no background and holds only those layers you put into that Smart Object.)
4. Add the Slices and save the objects into the formats you want while you're inside that edit mode.
5. If you change things in the Edit mode of a Smart Object, make sure to Save it. Just like you normally would save a document ( Ctrl+S )

Comment: that answers my question. I will try it now. One more thing. I have a layer with drop shadows effect and I want to export just the shadows but the slices I've made includes some part of the self object. Now I'm changing the object's blend options to opacity fill=0. But I have to do this every time I want to export or there is any trick?

Comment: @Totty Can't think of any way that would actually make much difference. ( As a side note, I'm gonna update my answer to mention Saving in the Smart object in the edit mode. )

Comment: Just occurred to me that you might not be aware, but you can click and drag the "Fill:" _text_ left and right which makes it rather easy to change the fill from 0 to 100 and vice versa.. and well, you could make Actions so that one action changes fill to 0% and other action changes fill to 100% .. that way you could just select layer and press hotkeys to do that, but as said... doesn't really make that much of a difference.

Comment: I know I can drag to right or left but I can't do that on multiple objects.. and I would have to remember all of them.. I will try actions. thanks (: But one more little question. is possible to export slices to a sprite (a big image that contain all that little images?) dirrectly

Comment: @Totty Good way is to use Sprite generators http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ ( This is not the only one, but I've seen it recomended a lot. This is what I've used quite a lot http://css-sprit.es/ ) They basically take bunch of saved images and knit a them into one img. As far as setting sprite sheet with multiple images in specific order/style.. I don't know any other way other than just manually placing them.. and I sometimes Drag layers ( Usually group them first ) from one document window to another. Which is in my opinion faster than right click and Duplicate to another document..

Comment: the problem is that some images will have the repeat-x ou repeat-y so it should be only one images per "row" or "column". The program takes care of it too?

Comment: @Totty No. And thats not something people do cause X and Y repeats just wont work together. You just cant do it. (Only if x and y repeats are the same, but that would just be a _repeat_ now wouldn't it) I made this example image of sprite sheets. http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/7193/spritesheet.jpg **(1.)** This is as basic as it gets (Like this you make 3 separate spread sheets for _no-repeat_, _repeat-x_ and _repeat-y_ ) **(2.)** This works in some cases.. **(3.)** This just won't work. So, you should use **(1.)** And you can make those 3 sheet's separately with Sprite generator.

Comment: Note that I made that by manually stacking them..

Comment: FYI, I accidentally presented repeat-x and repeat-y just the opposite way around, but anyways...

Comment: yes I know. I think I didn't explain well. When I was saying one image per "row" "column", means 1 image for the repeat-x and one image for the repeat-y. The question was if the app would recognize wherever a image will be looped x or y or I should do manually 2 images (for repeatx, y) + 1 for no-repeat images. But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you created your layout in PS, did you select transparent from the drop down labelled 'Background Contents'? If yes then when you save your slice as a png, toggle the eye on the background layer. Now you're saving the slice with a transparent background.

[image: Photoshop new window background contents transparent]

My box/frame now will be saved with a transparent background. Is this what you mean?

[image: Toggle background visibility]

Comment: I've updated my question in order to exactly show what I would want.. words are not enough to explain this.. (:

Comment: click on the layer eye to hide/unhide them, i guess this answer says it all....