# Photoshop slicing (CS5)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I've created a bunch of layer slices. However I need a way of hiding the background layers to make the images based on the layers have a transparent background when saved.

As i'm doing it now, I need to hide the background layers every time before selecting save for web. Is there an easier way?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/how-do-i-slice-drop-shadows-in-photoshop-when-there-is-another-layer-underneath/4729#4729 and if it's a slightly different case you can make action where you duplicate selected group or selected layers into a new document and use Image > Trim > Transparent pixels and then either add saving of the image to the action or leave that for you to do manually.

Comment: Very nice indeed :) I will have to read up on that, but it definitely looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is much easier way...

`Alt+click` the layer's eye that you want active(which you want to slice) by this  all the other layer will be hidden for once .

Repeating the same `Alt+click` will show the whole layers again.

hope this will help..

Comment: That's the way I do it at the moment, but it's definitely a valid point!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it that requires a bit more setup is to use layer comps along the way so that each slice (or group of slices for a single layout component) has its own comp with all BG and/or FG layers hidden.